# How to use custom labels from Django models.Choices field together with enum.auto?

Tags: python, django, enums

Before Django v3.0 I used to use `enum.Enum` together with `enum.auto` ([see reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum)) for my choices fields. The reason was mostly so I could use my enumeration class for type hints and `auto` enforced the usage of the enumeration class instead of using the constant value in code. However Django v3.0+ introduced the [enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) which is similar to the enum module but with some interesting features. I'd like to use it together with `enum.auto` but wasn't able so far.

The further I got was to something like this:

```
class MyChoices(models.IntegerChoices, Enum):
    FIRST = auto()
    SECOND = auto()
    THIRD = auto()
```

The enumeration values and the auto-generated labels are correct:

```
MyChoices
Out[13]: <enum 'MyChoices'>
MyChoices.choices
Out[14]: [(1, 'First'), (2, 'Second'), (3, 'Third')]
MyChoices.labels
Out[15]: ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
MyChoices.values
Out[16]: [1, 2, 3]
MyChoices.FIRST
Out[17]: <MyChoices.FIRST: 1>
```

The issue is when I try to define custom labels:

```
class MyChoices(models.IntegerChoices, Enum):
    FIRST = auto(), '1st'
    SECOND = auto(), '2nd'
    THIRD = auto(), '3rd'
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-cf882f261e5f>", line 1, in <module>
    class MyChoices(models.IntegerChoices, Enum):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/enums.py", line 28, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(metacls, classname, bases, classdict, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 219, in __new__
    enum_member = __new__(enum_class, *args)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'auto'
```

I suppose the issue is something conflicting with the inherited `Enum` class. I tried removing it but then `auto()` doesn't work properly. Does anyone have any ideas about how to make it work?

---

**Update:** I noticed the `Enum` is **not required** in my class in order to `auto()` work. My enumeration works without it with the auto-generated labels but it still doesn't work with custom labels.

Comment: Are you open to not using `auto`?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, if I replace it by integers and remove the Enum class it works, but I'm curious to know if it's possible to make them both work together.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is not possible without a patch to Django enumeration type. The exception described above occurs because the `auto` value is not solved by the time this piece of code is called, so it tries to use `int` to convert an `auto` instance. This only happens when the enumeration is a tuple, i.e. `auto()` and a label, because of this piece of code in `_EnumDict.__setitem__` (enum module):

```
        elif not _is_descriptor(value):
            if key in self:
                # enum overwriting a descriptor?
                raise TypeError('%r already defined as: %r' % (key, self[key]))
            if isinstance(value, auto):
                if value.value == _auto_null:
                    value.value = self._generate_next_value(key, 1, len(self._member_names), self._last_values[:])
                    self._auto_called = True
                value = value.value
```

This is OK when the enumeration is only `auto` but doesn't work when declared together with a label because `value` is a tuple. This is not an issue with the `enum` module itself because it doesn't expect tuples.